# Replace Update with Add button in new row within WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am working with `WPF Datagrid` and I am trying to create an `Add` button instead of the `Update` and `Delete` buttons in the new row.
[image]

Below is the code of the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgCust" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              PreviewKeyDown="dgCust_PreviewKeyDown" 
                              AddingNewItem="dgCust_AddingNewItem" 
                              BeginningEdit="dgCust_BeginningEdit" 
                              RowEditEnding="dgCust_RowEditEnding" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer ID"  Binding="{Binding ID}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone}" />
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                             <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
                             <local:NotBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
                        </ContentControl.Resources>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                              <Button Content="Update" Click="Update_Row_Button_Click"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsNewItem,Converter={StaticResource NotBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                              <Button Content="Delete" Click="Delete_Row_Button_Click"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsNewItem,Converter={StaticResource NotBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                                <Button Content="Add" Click="Add_Row_Button_Click"  CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsNewItem,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                          </StackPanel>
                          </ContentControl>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also added the namespace: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"`

What is the best solution of replacing the `Update` and `Delete` buttons with `Add` button in the new row?

**Edit:** Added the server side code:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class NotBoolToVisibilityConverter : BooleanToVisibilityConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to add it with a footer row.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use single column to display both buttons. That way solution will be easy as below:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Loaded="ContentControl_Loaded">   
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
                            <local:NotBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
                        </ContentControl.Resources>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="Update" Click="Button_Click"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsNewItem,Converter={StaticResource NotBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                            <Button Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click_1"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsNewItem,Converter={StaticResource NotBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                            <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click_2"  CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsNewItem,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**NotBoolToVisibilityConverter** is invert of BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

[image: Add Button]

**Adding Converter:**

```
public class NotBoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the following to the xaml document: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:namespace" but I'm still getting this error: the namespace Not BoolToVisibilityConverter does not exist in the namespace clr--namespace... Should I add any code on the server side?

Comment: @Hanady It's just a simple converter that will return visible value if pass a false value. I'll add that to answer. and local was just a reference to namespace of NotBoolToVisibilityConverter.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of code i'm missing but what i'm getting is that the three buttons are missing from all the rows except for the new now where the three buttons are shown. Not sure what is happening..

Comment: did you tried to put break points in the converter convert method?

Comment: well that's kind of impossible, if buttons are getting rendered anywhere that means value must have come through converter. Can you check this by making a separate demo first? Or update your code in question. I'll have a look.

Comment: @Hanady still works perfect for me. which .net framework are you using? IsNewRow property is available from 4.5 framework. and in case it's not available all buttons will be visible by default.

Comment: @Hanady which .net framework are you on? that may be the problem here.

Comment: why have you used <mui:DataGridTextColumn. is this any kind of framework?\